# Any way to make converting Images To PDFs faster

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I currently have a section of code that takes some images I generate and converts them to PDF files using PDFSharp.  The code works very well as far as I can tell but it takes about 4 to 6 seconds per page to do the conversion.  I'm just trying to find out if there is a faster way to do this conversion.  I've tried using iTextSharp but in addition to still taking the same amount of time, it did not render the images correctly.  Below is the code I use to create the PDFs as of now.

```vb
Private Sub OnThread_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs)
    Dim _thread As BackgroundWorker = DirectCast(sender, BackgroundWorker)
    Dim _arguments As Object() = DirectCast(e.Argument, Object())
    Dim _pages As List(Of Image) = DirectCast(_arguments(0), List(Of Image))
    Dim _filePath As String = DirectCast(_arguments(1), String)

    'this code works, but is pretty slow (about 4 - 5 seconds per page)
    Dim _pdfDocument As PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument = New PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument()

    For i As Integer = 0 To (_pages.Count - 1)
        Dim _page As Image = _pages(i)
        Dim _pdfPage As PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfPage = _pdfDocument.Pages.Add()
        Dim _pdfCanvas As PdfSharp.Drawing.XGraphics = PdfSharp.Drawing.XGraphics.FromPdfPage(_pdfPage)
        Dim _pdfImage As PdfSharp.Drawing.XImage = PdfSharp.Drawing.XImage.FromGdiPlusImage(_page)
        _pdfCanvas.DrawImage(_pdfImage, New Rectangle(0, 0, Convert.ToInt32(_pdfPage.Width.Point), Convert.ToInt32(_pdfPage.Height.Point)))
        _pdfImage.Dispose()
        _pdfCanvas.Dispose()
        _thread.ReportProgress(0, New Integer() {i + 1, _pages.Count})
    Next

    _pdfDocument.Save(_filePath)
    _pdfDocument.Close()
End Sub
```

Any solutions to this issue would be greatly appreciated.  I also welcome C# examples if that is what you know.  If it helps when I tested the speed using Stopwatch, the following line of code is the one that is taking all of the time to complete.

```vb
_pdfCanvas.DrawImage(_pdfImage, New Rectangle(0, 0, Convert.ToInt32(_pdfPage.Width.Point), Convert.ToInt32(_pdfPage.Height.Point)))
```

Comment: Try to convert multiple images in Parallel

Comment: I haven't messed with PDFSharp much, but the approach you listed seems like it'd be very inefficient.  GdiPlus (if I remember correctly) works in Bitmap form, and the Drawing of images likely works in another.  Effectively, it looks to me like you're converting the image format multiple times, and then resizing (either larger or smaller, depending upon the original image size) as you draw it.

Comment: It seems I didn't account for the slow down from running this code in the debugger.  Once compiled, each page takes a little under one second.  I don't think it can get any better than that.

Comment: @PriorityMark - I'm not sure what you mean, the XGraphics.DrawImage needs a XImage object and XImage can only be created from a file or a Drawing.Image object.  All the images I'm sending here are created as Drawing.Bitmap objects earlier in code.  I can't speak for what happens under the hood in the XImage.FromGDIPlusImage line but Stopwatch clocks its execution under 100ms.

Comment: `_pdfCanvas.DrawImage(_pdfImage, New Rectangle(0, 0, Convert.ToInt32(_pdfPage.Width.Point), Convert.ToInt32(_pdfPage.Height.Point)))` is effectively resizing the image to the size of the rectangle is it not?  That resize, if not written efficiently, can be very costly.  Like I said though, I haven't actually worked with this extension, and I certainly don't know what the rest of your code looks like.